# Need inputs on optimising web service calls from Perl

Tags: perl

Current implementation-
Divide the original file into files equal to the number of servers.
Ensure each server picks one file for processing.
Each server splits the file into 90 buckets.
Use ForkManager to fork 90 processes, each operating on a bucket.
The child processes will make the API calls.
Merge the output of child processes.
Merge the output of each server.

Stats-
The size of the content downloaded using the API call is 40KB.
On 2 servers, the above process for a 225k user file runs in 15 minutes. My aim is to finish a 10 million file in 30 minutes. (Hope this doesn't sound absurd!)

I contemplated using BerkeleyDB but, couldn't find how do I convert the BerkeleyDB file into normal ASCII file.

Comment: 225K on two servers in 15m is 450K per hour per server.  So assuming linear scaling ( which is not certain ) 10M in 30 minutes would require 45 servers

Comment: What does the BerkleyDB have to do with it? I think your bottleneck will not be reading the input data from disk or writing the results back. It will be the time it takes to do the web service calls. What kind of API are you talking about? REST, SOAP? There has to be a server that does the computing, too. How complex is the operation that server needs to do to your user data? hitting it with a lot of parallel requests might slow it down considerably. Talk to the people who run that service about this. If this is one-time, maybe you can send them the files to run on their side in batch.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a one-time operation to me. Although I don't understand the 30 minute limit, I have a few suggestions I know from experience.

First of all, as I said in my comment, your bottleneck will not be reading the data from your files. It will also not be writing the results back to a harddrive. The bottleneck will be in the transfer between your machines and the remote machines. Your setup sounds sophisticated, but that might not help you in this situation.

If you are hitting a webservice, someone is running that service. There are servers that can only handle a certain ammount of load. I have brought down the dev environment servers of a big logistics company with a very small load test I ran at night. Often, these things are equipped for long-term load, but not short, heavy load.

Since IT is all about *talking to each other* through various protocols, like web services or other APIs, you should also consider just talking to the people who run this service. If you have a business-relationship, that is easy. If not, try to find a way to reach them and to ask if their service is able to handle so many requests at all. You could end up with them excluding you permanently because to their admins it looks like you tried to [DDOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDOS#Distributed_attack) them.

I'd ask them if you could send them the files (or an excerpt of the data, cut down to what is relevant for processing) so they can do the operations in batch on their side. That way, you remove the load for processing everything as web requests, and the time it takes to do these requests.

Comment: The web service API is capable of handling 600 queries per second. I am only able to hit a peak of 250 qps using the setup mentioned in the original description. I was wondering whether threads(instead of ForkManager) would help me in increasing the qps.

Comment: Maybe your upstream is limited? I don't know if threads will make a difference. Maybe you should look at a report for your outgoing internet connection to determine if you can get enough bandwidth. On a different note, this is about a load test rather than actually sending production data, isn't it? Maybe you should run your program from different sources as in different machines on different internet connections.

Comment: Actually, this is production.